# Issues calculating NDVI from ASTER

Tags: imagery, land-cover, image-mosaic

I'm having an issue with ASTER data.

I have two mosaics; one for 2008 and one for 2012. Both are composed of 4 ASTER scenes and the scenes are all from the same two month period (i.e. no seasonal differences).

I have converted the values from DN values to *Radiance* (CORRECTION: reflectance value was calculated after radiance) and calculated for NDVI but the end result is absolutely meaningless (i.e. the NDVI range is between 1 and -1 but the comparison between two years can not detect change).

I think the reason for this is because the 2012 image looks very 'over-exposed' (i.e. there's little spectral difference between urban and pasture).

I think I might need to correct for atmospheric 'noise' but I had thought that AST14OTH images were already correct and that it wouldn't be necessary for ASTER14OTH images.

If anyone can shed light on why the images from the two years are so different and how to correct them - I would love to hear your advice.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Vegetation indices are not calculated from radiance, they are calculated from **reflectance**.

- Radiance is the *quantity* of radiation emitted from a surface within a solid angle of the instantaneous field of view of the sensor, with units of Watts per square meter per steradian. This will vary depending on illumination conditions (how sunny it is) and the characteristics of the sensor, among other things.
- Reflectance is the the *fraction* of radiation from a source (e.g. the Sun) that is reflected by a surface. Reflectance values are always between zero and one. When calculated perfectly, reflectance should be the same regardless of the sensor or illumination conditions. This makes sense when you consider that two different sensors *should* result in the same NDVI value for the same area.

The easiest way to get reflectance is to use a different ASTER product: [AST_07](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/aster_products_table/ast_07) has values that describe surface reflectance. The only note is that the decimal values between zero and one are multiplied by 1,000 so that the data can be stored in a smaller integer format. So a value of `774` in AST_07 represents a reflectance fraction of `0.774`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And thanks for catching an error, I had meant reflectance and not radiance.

I calculated radiance and then calculate reflectance using the following equation:

reflectance = pi * (Radiance.sat - Radiance.haze) * d2 / Esun * Cos (Solar Zenith Angle)

Unfortunately I can not acquire AST_07, or that would simplify my life.

Comment: @BonneLife What is the range of values resulting from your radiance to reflectance equation? You should also confirm that your order of operations is correct and that your software does cosines of degrees (and not radians).

Comment: The radiance values range between ~10 and ~160 whereas the reflectance values range between ~0.01 and ~0.7. I am aware of radian and degree issues. I have tried calculating reflectance with two different equations: reflectance = pi * (Radiance.sat - Radiance.haze) * d2 / Esun * Cos (Solar Zenith Angle) , reflectance= (PI x Radiance x d2) / (Irradiance x sin (PI x sun elevation angle / 180)). The first one calculated in Radians whereas the second one calculated with degrees. Both, however, gave me incomparable NDVI values. Any insight?? Thanks!

Comment: The reflectance values are in the correct range. For a sample pixel, what are the values of red reflectance, NIR reflectance, and NDVI that you're getting?